# In node.js, the post method is connected to get and a 404 error appears

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, axios

node.js, if you change the 'post' method to 'get' in the client, it works well, but 404 error appears only in the 'post' method. May I know why?

P.S Many people say the problem is caused by the failure to find the path '/api/insert/' on the server, but I don't think it's because it works well when you change to the 'get' method.

- client code

```
  const writePost = async () => {
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    const config = {
      headers: {
        withCredentials: true,
      },
      body: {
        title: writeData.title,
        content: writeData.content,
        register: writeData.register,
      },
    };
    try {
      //Successful response
      await axios
        .post("http://localhost:8000/api/insert", config)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          console.log(res.config);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      //Failed to respond
      console.log("write error", error);
    }
  };
```

- node code

```
const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const PORT = process.env.port || 8000;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: "",
  user: "",
  password: "",
  database: "",
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));

app.post("/api/insert", (req, res) => {
  var title = req.body.title;
  var content = req.body.content;
  var register = req.body.register;
  const sqlQuery =
    "INSERT INTO BOARD (BOARD_TITLE, BOARD_CONTENT, REGISTER_ID) VALUES (?,?,?);";
  db.query(sqlQuery, [title, content, register], (err, result) => {
    res.send(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: you change `post` to `get` on the client or the server side?

Comment: You got it.... :)

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your setup exactly (as described, adding writeData varible in client code, and `app.listen(PORT)` in server.js) and worked for me, the most possible cause is PORT is being defined to something else than 8000, it checks for process.env.port before hand, removing that fixes it.

Comment: It seems irrelevant to port 8000. Because it works normally when you change from 'POST' to 'GET'.

Comment: well, we know that the code works atleast, so it has to be a problem with the environment. could be firewall settings (although that would be a access denied error(i think?)), or outdated packages (i doubt it). make sure everything is up to date, and check firewall that inbound post requests wouldn't be denied

Comment: Problem Reason Found.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you enter the url path in your browser, it displays the 'get' method, so it is one-sided for the error to appear. To test the 'post' method, use the 'form' tag 'method' 'post', or the 'controller get post' or 'postman'.